# Listnodes in Java (Beginner Level)

Tags: java

I am currently a programming student in UW Madison, and I'm hoping someone can help me with an assignment.  Right now we are learning about listnodes, but I'm not sure I fully grasp the concept.  Here are the questions:

Complete the following method according to the specification.

```
// Insert a new Listnode<E> containing d after the first n Listnodes in
// chain. If n is less than 1 or bigger than the number of Listnodes in
// chain, throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.
// Precondition: chain has at least one node
//
// Examples:
//  chain: "A"           n: 1   d: "B"  chain: "A" -> "B"
//  chain: "A" -> "B"    n: 1   d: "C"  chain: "A" -> "C" -> "B"
//  chain: "A"           n: 2   d: "B"  IndexOutOfBoundsException
public static <E> void insertAfter(Listnode<E> chain, int n, E d) {
```

Complete the following method according to the specification.

Hint: Consider using two references to step through the chain of nodes and think carefully about when to advance them.

```
// Remove all nodes in the chain whose data is equal to d (as determined by
// the equals() method of the E class).
// Preconditions: chain is not null and uses a header node (the first
// Listnode does not contain any data), no data in the chain after the
// header node is null, d is not null
//
// Examples (Hdr means header node):
//      chain: "Hdr"                   d: "A"  chain: "Hdr"
//      chain: "Hdr" -> "A"            d: "A"  chain: "Hdr"
//      chain: "Hdr" -> "A" -> "B"     d: "A"  chain: "Hdr" -> "B"
//      chain: "Hdr" -> "A" -> "A"     d: "A"  chain: "Hdr"
public static <E> void removeAll(Listnode<E> chain, E d) {
```

And the following are the answers I came up with:

```
1) public static <E> void insertAfter(Listnode<E> chain, int n, E d)
{
    int count = 0;
    Listnode<E> curr = chain;
    while (curr != null)
    {
        count++;
        curr = curr.getNext();
    }
    if (n < 1 || n > count)
        throw IndexOutOfBoundsException;
    Listnode<E> temp = chain;
    for (int x = 1; x < n; x++)
        temp = temp.getNext();
    temp.setNext(d,temp.getNext());
}

2)  public static <E> void removeAll(Listnode<E> chain, E d) 
{
    int count = 0;
    Listnode<E> curr = chain;
    while (curr != null)
    {
        count++;
        curr = curr.getNext();
    }
    Listnode<E> temp = chain;
    for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
    {
        if (temp.getData.equals(d))
            temp.setNext(temp.getNext().getNext());
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
}
```

According to the notes I took, these answers should be right, but I don't understand some of the concepts.  For example, why are we supposed to use a temporary variable?  I understand that by stepping through the chain, you are essentially erasing all the nodes that came before the node you are currently working with, but how does using a temporary variable solve that problem?

If I've made any mistakes, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: To get to the next one, you need the current one. To get to that next one's next one, it needs to be the current, ad nauseam.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion requires the overwriting of pointers, in this case pointers to the next and previous items in your list. If you don't use a temporary variable, then when you overwrite the pointers to the item in the list, that item will be lost and will be unrecoverable, at least in the order that you had it, as the order was changed.

In other words, it "just works." :P